# How to modify my array to get 4 different array based on the value of the objects inside the array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of objects, each of these objects have a capability attribute, there are 4 different types, I want to split the array into 4 different arrays based on what their capability value is.

Tried to map but couldnt work out how to do it based on one of their values.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.questionsService.getQuestions().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.questions = [];
            Object.keys(data).map((key)=>{ this.questions.push(data[key])});
            console.log(this.questions);
        }
    );
}
```

Examples of the objects:

```
{
    "Capability": "Associate",
    "SubCategory": "Core Skills",
    "Skill": "Communication",
    "SkillID": 1
},
{
    "Capability": "CCM",
    "SubCategory": "Other Skills",
    "Skill": "Data Protection/ GDPR",
    "SkillID": 34
}
```

I want the array of questions to be split into four different arrays, an array each for the different values of capability.

Comment: Can you cut down your code to the actually necessary code? I fail to see the part your asking about.

Comment: there you go, its more of a general question

Comment: You might want to show an example of object and the desired output of that object after splitting aka in json how do they look like

Comment: Please show a json example of your questions object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Edited to show an example of the objects, output needs to be four arrays for the 4 different values of capability

Comment: Its not a duplicate of that, that is in plain javascript

Comment: Javascript is valid typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is same with here [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key/40774906)

```
var myArray = [
{ capability: 1, id: 1},
{ capability: 1, id: 2},
{ capability: 2, id: 3},
{ capability: 3, id: 4},
{ capability: 4, id: 5}
]
var result = myArray.reduce(function (r, a) {
r[a.capability] = r[a.capability] || [];
r[a.capability].push(a);
return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```